# Storing data between minimize app

Tags: android

I don't know how to properly formulate my question, because I don't know what the word is called. (I found minimize to be the closest word.)

The word I'm looking for can be  described as: When the user minimizes the app either by: clicking the back-button, clicking the home button, cycling to another currently running app, or by turning off the screen. All of these actions seem to have the same result. So I am assuming they are doing the same thing in the operating system.

Here is my issue: When I "minimize" the app in any way, then re-open it, `onCreate` and `onResume` gets called - making my app run as though ran for the first time. Which means the app loses information.

I have tried storing the information by using `onSaveInstanceState`, but to no avail. Here is my code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //irrelevant stuff going on here..

    if(savedInstanceState == null){
        allPlanes = new ArrayList<>();
        currentPlaneNumber = 0;
    }
    else{
        //This never happens..
        Log.i("Debug...", "saved state exists!");
        allPlanes = savedInstanceState.getParcelableArrayList("ALL_PLANES");
        currentPlaneNumber = savedInstanceState.getInt("CURRENT_PLANE_NUMBER");
    }
}

@Override
public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();

    //Everything going on in this method concerns data transferring between two activities, and works as intended. Not sure if this is relevant for my question..

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    if(intent.hasExtra("CURRENT_PLANE_NUMBER")){
        currentPlaneNumber = Integer.parseInt(intent.getStringExtra("CURRENT_PLANE_NUMBER"));
    }
    if(intent.hasExtra("ALL_PLANES")){
        allPlanes = intent.getParcelableArrayListExtra("ALL_PLANES");
        allPlanesLength = allPlanes.size() -1;
        updatePlane();
        displayImage();
    }
    else{
        AsyncTask asyncTask = new AsyncTask(getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.list));
        asyncTask.register(this);
        asyncTask.execute();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);

    //This never happens? (I never see the log output below)

    Log.i("Debug...", "onRestore called!");
}

@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

    //This is me trying to store the data between the "minimizing"..

    outState.putParcelableArrayList("ALL_PLANES", allPlanes);
    outState.putInt("CURRENT_PLANE_NUMBER", currentPlaneNumber);
}
```

1. What's the correct term for what I call "minimizing"?
2. Is `onSaveInstanceState` the way to handle this problem?
3. What am I doing wrong? (How can I successfully store this data between "minimizing"?)

Comment: which type of data you want to store

Comment: As you can see from the onSaveInstanceState I'm trying to store a parcelable ArrayList (allPlanes) and an int (currentPlaneNumber). Plane is just a class I've made.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> All of these actions seem to have the same result

Not exactly.

Clicking BACK destroys the activity.

Your other scenarios simply move that activity to the background. If you do not have another activity that is now in the foreground — so your entire app is now in the background — your process is likely to be terminated soon, though typically not immediately. This has the net effect of destroying all of your activities along the way.

> When I "minimize" the app in any way, then re-open it, onCreate and onResume gets called

Not necessarily. Your activity instance is called with `onCreate()` when it is created. That is either because:

- This is the first time it has been created, or
- A previous instance was destroyed, and a fresh one is being created

> I have tried storing the information by using onSaveInstanceState, but to no avail

That will handle some of your scenarios (e.g., HOME, switch to another app), for a short while (less than 30 minutes).

In general, if you want to hold onto data, save it in a persistent data store: database, `SharedPreferences`, or some other sort of file.

> What's the correct term for what I call "minimizing"?

In all four cases, your activity is being stopped (i.e., it is being called with `onStop()`), because it is no longer visible.

> Is onSaveInstanceState the way to handle this problem?

This will handle configuration changes (e.g., user rotates the device). Depending on circumstances, it may cover other scenarios. It's not a general-purpose data storage mechanism. We use it for identifiers and small in-flight data that we are not ready to store permanently, but if the user does not return to our app for a day and therefore we lose, it is not a big problem.

> How can I successfully store this data between "minimizing"?

Databases, `SharedPreferences`, or other forms of files.

Comment: So the correct way to store this data is (for example) using SharedPreferences combined with the onStop() method?

Comment: @Phrosen: In terms of where you save the data, that is up to you. In terms of when you save the data, `onStop()` would be the latest time. Typically, I save the data when the data changes or when the user does something positive in the UI to say "save this data".

Comment: How would I go about saving my ArrayList<Plane> using SharedPreferences? I googled and found ArrayList<String> could be saved using HashSet, but this doesn't seem to work with my custom object?

Comment: @Phrosen SharedPreferences are intended for storing relatively simple data. For more complex data, such as custom objects, you should use a file or database.

Answer (score 0):

What you call "minimized" is related to [the Activity Lifecycle](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities.html#Lifecycle). Each state has a name, such as Paused, Stopped, or Destroyed rather than just "minimized". I suggest you take some time to learn more about this important topic in Android development.

As for your question, storing data with `onSaveInstanceState()` is very temporary. It is intended for situations when your Activity is destroyed and quickly recreated, such as during a configuration change. If the user leaves your app for a significant amount of time, you need to store data more permanently. To learn about the available options, I suggest you read [the Data Storage Developer's Guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/index.html).

Note that both links I gave above are from [the Official Android Developer Documentation](https://developer.android.com/). You should take the time to familiarize yourself with this site. It is a great resource to help you understand the fundamentals of Android development.